# Why different primary key queries have huge speed difference in innodb?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have a simple table `Test`:

- `id`, primary key;
- `id2`, index;
- and other 50+ all kinds of type columns;

And I know that if I `select id from Test`, it'll use secondary index `id2` rather that primary index (clustered index) as stated in [this post](https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/innodb-primary-key-versus-secondary-index-an-interesting-lesson-from-explain/).

If I force queries using primary index, why do the results time differ a lot when selecting different columns?

##### Query 1

`select id, url from Test order by id limit 1000000, 1`, uses only 500ms+ and here is the explain:

```
MySQL [x]> explain select id, url from Test order by id limit 1000000, 1;                                                                                                                                                                                        
+----+-------------+-----------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+---------+----------+-------+
| id | select_type | table     | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows    | filtered | Extra |
+----+-------------+-----------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+---------+----------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | Test      | NULL       | index | NULL          | PRIMARY | 8       | NULL | 1000001 |   100.00 | NULL  |
+----+-------------+-----------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+---------+----------+-------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

##### Query 2

`select * from Test order by id limit 1000000, 1` uses only 2000ms+, and here is the explain:

```
MySQL [x]> explain select * from Test order by ID limit 1000000, 1;                                                                                                                                                                                                     
+----+-------------+-----------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+---------+----------+-------+
| id | select_type | table     | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows    | filtered | Extra |
+----+-------------+-----------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+---------+----------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | Test      | NULL       | index | NULL          | PRIMARY | 8       | NULL | 1000001 |   100.00 | NULL  |
+----+-------------+-----------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+---------+----------+-------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

I don't see any difference between both explains. So why is there such a huge difference regarding result time, since they use the same clustered index?

Comment: Do you have text, long text, blob (etc) fields in that table? That might explain it.

Comment: @SalmanA I do have text and varchar columns, but after deleting all these columns in query and `select <all other columns here>` still needs 1500ms+, so i don't think text is the key reason. I still believe there may be a difference in 'scanning the clustered index'.

Comment: because this query `select id, url` mysql will try to get only two columns (`id, url`) but `select *` might get all data that are a lot of different logical  read.

Comment: That is why people say to avoid using `select *` and try to use `select` as clear columns.

Comment: @D-Shih I think both of the query need to read all the columns of this target row, and the former only returns two columns. So there shouldn't be so huge a difference. Is it reasonable?

Comment: does it work if you change it to `select * from t where id = (select id from t order by id limit 1000000, 1)`?

Comment: @SalmanA Yeah, `select * from t where id = (select id from t order by id limit 1000000, 1)` uses also 500ms+, so the reason is **not** `loading all the fields is slow`. Thanks, but still why? Don't both the queries in the question scan the same clustered index the same way?

Comment: Please provide `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON` for each version.

Comment: Run each timing test twice so you can avoid issues with caching.

Comment: @RickJames Thanks for your kindly reminder, I run them all more than once. And I found the reason finally, please refer to my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the reason finally... It's because the implementation of mysql [limit](https://mp.weixin.qq.com/s/CM7a6XageZEZ4008Ha8bew). (sorry that I just found this Chinese explanation, no English version)

In Query1 and Query2 above, here is what `limit` do:

1. Mysql query the clustered index, get the first row;
2. Mysql will convert the first row to result;
3. then before sending it to the client, Mysql finds that there is a limit 1000000, so the first row is not the right answer...
4. Mysql then just go to the 2nd row and convert it to result;
5. then before sending it to the client, Mysql finds that there is a limit 1000000, so the second row is not the right answer...;
6. again and again, till it findss the 1000001th row, after converting it to result, it matches the `limit 1000000, 1` clase;
7. so finally, this is the right answer, and send it to the client;

However, it has converted totally 1000000 rows. So in the above question, **it's the cost between 'all fields conversion(`select *`) multiply 1000000 rows' vs. 'one/two field conversion(`select id/url`) multiply 1000000 rows'**. No doubt that the former is far slower than the latter.

Don't know why mysql `limit` behaives so clumsy, but it just is...

Comment: Did you see any noticable improvement when using a where clause + limit sub query?

Comment: "Lazy loading" _should_ have avoided "converting 1M rows to result", but apparently not.  The subquery approach is effectively what "lazy loading" does.

Comment: yeah, query return immediately. 'cause mysql uses where clause to locate the row and only converts all fields for only one row.

Comment: @RickJames yeah, no lazy loading for `limit` implementation, rediculous...

Answer (score 1):

For the following query:

```
select id, url from t order by id limit 1000000, 1
```

MySQL seems to *read* 1,000,000 rows ordered by id instead of *skipping* them.

I would suggest changing the query to this:

```
select * from t where id = (select id from t order by id limit 1000000, 1)
```

MySQL seems to do a better job at skipping 1,000,000 rows when limit is placed inside a sub query.

Comment: So the last words `since we only want the nth id MySQL will scan the index instead of rows`, could you explain more precisely which `index` does it mean? If it's clustered index, there should be no difference between scanning table rows and the clustered index. If it's not clustered index, then what kind of index is it? A secondary index about primary key(I didn't hear about this one)?

Comment: `select id` should be faster than `select *` as MySQL does not need to access data pages (the leaves).

Comment: Yeah, it sounds resonable. But 'scanning' the clustered index means traversing from the first row in the first leaf page to the last row in the last leaf page... So I just can't understand why `select id` don't access the data pages(the leaves)... I really think both of them will access the data pages...

Comment: Yeah, query in my question is `select id, url from Test`(not `select id from t`), and as you said it should access leaf nodes to get `url` value. So does `select *`. But actual result is that `select id, url` still be much more faster than `selcect *`. Thanks for your patience in advanced

Comment: To recap, the query without where clause will read 1,000,001 rows. The query with where clause still needs to read 1,000,001 rows for the _subquery_ part but that would be faster\* since subquery only needs the id column and not the data. The data (url or `*`) is fetched in outer query and that for exactly one row. (\* I am not exactly sure why it is faster but my guess is that reading values for columns other that the id cause additional I/O).

Comment: @SalmanA - [re: second Comment, above] False (in this case).  The `PRIMARY KEY` is "clustered" with the data.  It must get to the 'data pages' even to find `id`.

Comment: @SalmanA I found the answer but the explanation is too long, so I post it as [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72173942/7676237). Anyway, thanks for your patient help~

Answer (score -1):

1. check sql profile，Determine more information

mysql> show profile

2.mysql explain is not very powerful yet.

3.What kind of scene needs limit 10000？